# R shinyjs - catch change class event

Tags: jquery, r, shinydashboard, shinyjs

With shinydashboardPlus, how can I get the class of an element when the class changes with jQuery and shinyjs?

Here's an example where the right sidebar is opened/closed - I want to capture the open/close event from the addition/removal of the body class:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
      enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
      rightSidebarIcon = "gears"
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.rsb_status = function(){$('body').hasClass('control-sidebar-open')}")
    ),
    rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
      background = "dark",
      rightSidebarTabContent(
        id = 1,
      )
    ),
    title = "Right Sidebar"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(
      js$rsb_status()
      , {
        message("Class changed!")
      }
    )
  }
)
```